# Pearson correlation coefficient with few clusters

Tags: correlation, clustering, references, bootstrap

I want to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient and its significance of two variables. Since the data is clustered, I intend to bootstrap on the clusters.

However, [Cameron & Miller, 2015](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/Cameron_Miller_JHR_2015_February.pdf) suggest to use the Wild cluster bootstrap for regression analysis, if there are fewer than around 50 clusters.

Since I couldn't find any sources so far, to what extent might this also apply to the Pearson correlation coefficient?